# How to use MongoDB c# driver in NET 4.5 application?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have built an c# .NET 4.8 application uses assembly with freshest MongoDB c# Driver. It works fine.
But I have another NET 4.5 application.
It cannot use this assembly because it should use NET 4.5.
The question is: how can I rebuild my assembly to use NET 4.5 and MongoDB c# driver?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MongoDB.Driver 2.7.3 nuget package. This is the latest version which supports .net 4.5.

[image]

Comment: Ok. Does this version work with the latest  MongoDB server?

Comment: Also, the calls worked in the latest driver                var dbClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
                var dbClient = new MongoClient(); in that version generates exceptions

Comment: @ZedZip what’s the exception?

Comment: There is:
public string connectionString = “mongodb://localhost:27017”;
var dbClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);

Method not found: ‘MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ClusterSettings 
MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ClusterSettings.With(MongoDB.Driver.Optional1<MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.ClusterConnectionMode>, 
MongoDB.Driver.Optional1<MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.ConnectionModeSwitch>, MongoDB.Driver.Optional1<System.Nullable1>, 
...